# Whats the best way to save user inputted variables on php without a database?

Tags: php, database, variables, storage, global

I would like to have an page, where you can set various things. For example: BoardName or Boardurl. Its mainly for administrators for the website. But I want to use for instance $Boardname in almost every page (for example: I have header.php and in the code i have:

> include 'variables.php'

Or something in that region. Variables.php is the place where the variables are stored).

Now have I heard of global variables in PHP. But I have also heard that this is not recommended at all (due to loading time). Then I heard about storing it in a database. Which is my only solution if this wont give me an answer.

For an extra example: XenForo has options where Boardname etc. also get based on user input.

Thanks in advance.
I hope I made myself clear

Comment: Session? ->`$_SESSION`

Comment: I don't see how they're related? Using a variable in every page sounds like a scope or code-organization question.... Asking about alternative persistent-storage mechanisms is completely different. Lump in your comment about `global` and its performance drawbacks and I'm completely lost.

Comment: Sessions arent stored forever. Right?

Comment: Can you use a flat-file database like SQLite?

Comment: The problem is, I am trying to not fill the database. If it can be done without, i would like it that way.

Comment: @MrDikke no the aren't stored for ever! OR you can use cookies, but these can be disabled or deleted

Comment: "But I have also heard that this is not recommended at all (due to loading time)." One include with few variables shouldn't be a problem, but maybe i am wrong... :)

Comment: What does that mean? "not fill the database"

Comment: Yeah, but i dont know how many variables I want to store (yet).

Comment: Your question is indeed a bit weird. If you want to set the data for one request (don't keep it for next page) there is no problem with globals. If you need a wider scope you will need to have $_SESSION or $_COOKIE. if you're looking for something else than a database you could use xml, yaml, ini files, ...

Comment: I do want to store it for multiple pages. But i want to save them "forever". If they are set. I want to be able to say $Boardname everywhere.

Comment: What variables do you have in `variables.php`?

Comment: @MrDikke If you want to save them for ever then use a `database` or files like `.xml` or `.csv`

Comment: @cuSK I gave 2 examples; Boardname and BoardUrl.
Rizier123 What would be the best way for approaching that?

Comment: Than I believe Rocket Hazmat has the best idea (sqlite). If you really don't want to use a simple db than go with xml, yml, csv, ...

Comment: I prefer you can use the variables directly from the file `variables.php`. Why don't you want to do that? As per your need. The variables are already **stored in the file permanently**.

Comment: The variables are user input (with $_POST), so what would be an way to saving that in variables.php @cuSK

Comment: So do you mean that the variables change for each and every user according to their input independently? Or will it be changed once and used by all the other users.

Comment: Once, and used by everyone.

Comment: @MrDikke, wow, that's really great. Then, I have an idea. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are basically thinking of a config file so you could have something like this:

**config.txt** JSON encoded object/array

```
{"BoardName":"a board name","Boardurl":"a board url"}
```

**Put this code at the top of all files which need the variables**

```
extract((array)json_decode(file_get_contents('config.txt')));
```

This will allow you to use `$BoardName` and `$Boardurl` wherever you please.

---

When you need to write back to the file then do this:

```
$new_conf = array();
if(isset($_POST['BoardName']))
{
    $new_conf['BoardName'] = $_POST['BoardName'];
}
if(isset($_POST['Boardurl']))
{
    $new_conf['Boardurl'] = $_POST['Boardurl'];
}

if($new_conf)
{
    file_put_contents('config.txt', json_encode(array_merge((array)json_decode(file_get_contents('config.txt')), $new_conf)));
}
else
{
    // no conf parameters given, do nothing
}
```

---

**DISCLAIMER**

This method is highly prone to errors and does not scale well in the slightest bit. As soon as you get more than one admin then tish with hit the fan hard. If you get tons and tons of users then you could definitely end up with some disk access speed issues.

Comment: And how can people enter this in the admin panel as an variable (using $_Post and a form)?

Comment: How would you possibly bring for example 10 variables in this. Because it would replace over each other right?

Comment: @MrDikke In `array('BoardName'=>$_POST['BoardName'])` just add as many key=>value pairs as you need

Comment: Well it works, but the problem I am having is: If the admin doesnt set anything the submit button acts as a reset. Is there a way with if(isset) to work together with this? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @MrDikke of course there is, check out the edit

Comment: MMh, made my own edits to the first one, it works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create your custom ini file, let's say user.ini file.

Inside this user ini file mention all variables.

user.ini sample content
; This is a sample configuration file

; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini

[settings]
cust_file_size= 12MB
error_log_path= "log/debug/"

[path_settings]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"


than for reading you can just do 
$user_settings_array = parse_ini_file("user.ini", true);
print_r($ini_array);

Than output will:

Array
(
    [settings] => Array
        (
             [cust_file_size] =>12MB
             [error_log_path] =>log/debug/
         )
    [path_settings] =>Array
        (    [path] =>/usr/local/bin
             [URL]  =>http://www.example.com/~username
        }


I hope this will help you.

Thanks
```

Answer (score -1):

In the page where you post input variables, say **`input.php`**. Use the following code. And remember the following points to do that.

- The `$content` variable is fed with all the needed php variables using concatenation.
- Don't forget to include `<?php` and `?>` at the beginning and at the end of the `$content` variable.
- `\` escaping the dollar sign is must, which looks like `\$`, used for creating a new variable in your external file.
- Use `{}` surrounding the variables and also place a semi-colon `;` followed by a blank-space  . This blank-space matters a lot. And try to include one in every possible occasion.
- Finally use single-quotes surrounding the variable `'{}'`. Even if its a number. Because as you know that, PHP variables are parsed automatically.

The code in **`input.php`** looks like this:

```
$content = "<?php ";
$content .= "\$Boardname='{$_POST['Boardname']}'; ";
$content .= "\$BoardUrl='{$_POST['BoardUrl']}'; ";
$content .= "?>";
file_put_contents("variables.php", $content);
```

And then, you can use the **`variables.php`** as simple as follows:

```
include 'variables.php';
```

I hope it's the best solution for your need/issue.